# How should I create queries to show which employee's scores are declining?

Tags: mysql

[image]

How should I create queries to show which employee's scores are declining?
This is what I've tried, but the information turned out all duplicating

```
SELECT e.Employee_ID
     , v.Evaluation_ID
     , Scores
     , c.Career_year
  FROM Employee e
     , Evaluation v
     , Career c
 WHERE e.Employee_ID = v.Employee_ID
 ORDER 
    BY Scores DESC;
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. Show what you have tried, show what you expect the output to be. Lookup "how to ask a question" on stackoverflow for helpful information on how to ask a question that gets useful answers, and the types of questions allowed on SO.

Comment: this is what I've tried, but turned out all the information duplicating          
SELECT Employee.Employee_ID, Evaluation.Evaluation_ID, Scores, Career.Career_year
FROM Employee, Evaluation, Career
WHERE Employee.Employee_ID=Evaluation.Employee_ID
ORDER BY Scores DESC;

Comment: Don't put code in the comments. Please edit your question and add the info there.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any date in the Evaluation table, so how can you determine the order of the scores? Is Evaluation_ID increasing (higher number is more recent) over time?

Comment: i include it in the career table, there is one evaluation_ID for each employee every year.Yes the higher the number, the more recent it is

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: So Career_Year plus Employee_ID in Evaluations is unique? And you don't really need anything from the Career table, right?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
SELECT 
    a.Employee_ID, 
    ev_last.Evaluation_ID, 
    ev_last.Scores,
    ev_prev.Evaluation_ID, 
    ev_prev.Scores,
    Career.Career_year 
FROM Employee a
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        b.Career_Year as `last_eval_year`,
        b.Employee_ID,
        b.Scores
    FROM Evaluation b
    ORDER BY b.Career_Year DESC
    WHERE b.Employee_ID = a.Employee_ID
    LIMIT 1) ev_last
ON ev_last.Employee_ID = a.Employee_ID
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        c.Career_Year as `last_eval_year`,
        c.Employee_ID,
        c.Scores
    FROM Evaluation b
    ORDER BY b.Career_Year DESC
    WHERE c.Employee_ID = a.Employee_ID
    LIMIT 1,1) ev_prev
ON ev_prev.Employee_ID = a.Employee_ID
WHERE ev_prev.Scores > ev_last.Scores
```

It only compares the last two evaluations. It returns those employees where the previous score is higher that the last score.